# Synchronize two databases in Symfony

Tags: mysql, database, symfony, drush

Is there any similar tool like Drush (for Drupal) but in this case for Symfony2

To keep synchronized two or more databases for differents users in local development.

Comment: Your best bet is [Doctrine Migrations](http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/DoctrineMigrationsBundle/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

Try [Doctrine Migrations](http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/DoctrineMigrationsBundle/index.html)
or [phinx](https://github.com/robmorgan/phinx) but I suggest doctrine migrations since you are using symfony

Answer (score 0):

As [Rena Kolta](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4577836/rana-kolta) already mentioned, use [Doctrine Migrations](http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/DoctrineMigrationsBundle/index.html).

If you changed some entities and their database config, run:

```
app/console doctrine:migrations:diff
```

the differences are stored within the /app/DoctrineMigrations Folder and could be pushed into the repository. If the other user pulls the repository just run the command:

```
php app/console doctrine:database:drop --force
php app/console doctrine:database:create
php app/console doctrine:migrations:migrate --no-interaction
php app/console doctrine:schema:update --force
```

And i you have some sample data run the fixtures command:

```
php app/console doctrine:fixtures:load --no-interaction
```